# Как убрать отступ справа?

Tags: css

Вот сетка из элементов в 3 колонки, но после 3 блока есть отступ 10рх из-за чего появляется нежелательное поле. Дело в том что если убрать это через nth-child(3n) то при сужении сетка рушится, как быть?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none; }

p{
    border: 1px black solid;
}
.q1 div{
    background: black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 280px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.q1{
    border: 1px red solid;
    max-width:632px; 
    margin: auto;
     display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="q1">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: что значит нежелательное поле?

Comment: @L. Vadim Поле справа от каждого элемента div в контейнере. Нужно чтобы первый и последние элементы прилегали к границе контейнера, но при сужении когда столбцов становится 2 сетка не теряла форму.

Comment: @L. Vadim Я сделал так: Убрал поле у каждого третьего блока и уменьшил ширину контейнера. Потом кода сетка рассыпалась, в медиазапросе вернул поле третьим блокам и убрал у вторых и т.д. Это   считаеться правильным? вот https://jsfiddle.net/ckbLgjdc/

Comment: да хорошое решение

Comment: L. Vadim А не будет проблем с кроссбраузерностью? может когда у одного браузера медиазапрос сработает в одном месте а у другого в другом и получиться несостыковочка.

Answer (score 2):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
}

.q1-w{    
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 632px;
}

.q1{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content:center;
    margin: -5px;
}

.q1-item-w{
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    width: 33.3333%;
}
.q1-item{
    background: black;
    height: 280px;
}
```

```html
<div class="q1-w">
<div class="q1">
<div class="q1-item-w"><div class="q1-item"></div></div>
<div class="q1-item-w"><div class="q1-item"></div></div>
<div class="q1-item-w"><div class="q1-item"></div></div>
<div class="q1-item-w"><div class="q1-item"></div></div>
<div class="q1-item-w"><div class="q1-item"></div></div>
<div class="q1-item-w"><div class="q1-item"></div></div>
<div class="q1-item-w"><div class="q1-item"></div></div>
<div class="q1-item-w"><div class="q1-item"></div></div>
<div class="q1-item-w"><div class="q1-item"></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо но, то что сетка рушится так должно быть. Я про то что когда она рушится блоки становятся не ровно. Что если через точки останова подравнивать эти блоки добавляя поле  и убирая в других вот так?  jsfiddle.net/ckbLgjdc

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое решение - это для `.q1 div` дать `margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;`

Comment: Но в таком случае крайние блоки не будут приживаться к границе

Comment: насколько я вижу в вашем примере слева тоже есть отступ. и еще раз - я предложил самое простое, быстрое решение. оно не может быть идеальным, само собой это компромисс.