# Как выровнять колонки по краям?

Tags: css

Имеются товары, выровненные с помощью flex. Нужно чтобы колонки с товарами по краям были  всегда прижаты к краям контейнера `.wrapper` при любом разрешении экрана.
Проблема заключается в том, что последний ряд должен быть прижат влево.
Можно было бы решить задачу, установив для блока `.grid` свойство `justify-content: space-between`, но если будет мало товаров, между товарами будет много места.
Поэтому для блока `.grid` установлено свойство `justify-content: flex-start`.
При большой разрешении экрана колонок в ряду должно быть 6, потом 5, 3, 2, в зависимости от размера экрана.
Кстати не обязательно должно быть выравнивание с помощью flex, можно и с помощью обычных display: inline-block.
https://jsfiddle.net/76k3yefy/

```css
.container{
    background: #3fb8af;
}
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1440px;
    background: #fff;
}
.grid{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.gcell{
    display: inline-block;
    outline: 1px solid #000;
    width: 80%;
    flex-basis: 80%;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 1% 30px;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 200px;
}
.product{
    width: 90%;
    outline: 1px solid blue;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)  {
    .gcell{
        width: 50%;
        flex-basis: 50%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1024px)  {
    .gcell{
        width: 33%;
        flex-basis: 33%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1280px)  {
    .gcell{
        width: 20%;
        flex-basis: 20%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1440px)  {
    .gcell{
        width: 16.66%;
        flex-basis: 16.66%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="gcell"><div class="product"></div></div>
            <div class="gcell"><div class="product"></div></div>
            <div class="gcell"><div class="product"></div></div>
            <div class="gcell"><div class="product"></div></div>
            <div class="gcell"><div class="product"></div></div>
            <div class="gcell"><div class="product"></div></div>
            <div class="gcell"><div class="product"></div></div>
            <div class="gcell"><div class="product"></div></div>
            <div class="gcell"><div class="product"></div></div>
            <div class="gcell"><div class="product"></div></div>
            <div class="gcell"><div class="product"></div></div>
            <div class="gcell"><div class="product"></div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

на рисунках ниже примеры того, как должно выглядеть на разных экранах.
тут видно, как должны быть выровнены по краю и нижний ряд прижат влево

[image: 1440]
1440px

[image: 1280]
1280px

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
1024px

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
768px

Comment: у кого какие идеи?

Comment: Не понятно что тебе нужно... ты хочешь выравнивать по краям, но не хочешь большого расстояния между элементами, как ты себе это чисто  логически представляешь?

Comment: @A.Ivankov, логически ничего сложного здесь представлять.  Взгляни на рисунки

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/612022/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0/612037#612037

Comment: @mJeevas, по ссылке не соответствует моему вопросу

Comment: @word тогда не понятно что вам надо. Чем не соответствует пример по ссылке?

Comment: @mJeevas, уберите один блок из примера по вашей ссылке и посмотрите, все блоки в центре, а нужно чтобы нижний блок был прижат влево!

Comment: Только так  ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744164/flex-box-align-last-row-to-grid

Comment: @word, ну дак если убрать там выравнивание по центру, будет то что надо?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможное решение — отказаться от FlexBox и применить старый дедовский метод основанный на свойстве **text-align**. Последняя строка по умолчанию выравнивается влево (для европейской письменности); впрочем, это настраивается с помощью **text-align-last**.

```css
.product-container {
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 0px;
}
.product-container > * {
  display: inline-block;

  /* если не устраивает выравнивание по базовой линии */
  vertical-align: text-top;

  /* восстанавливаем предыдущие значения */
  text-align: start;
  font-size: medium;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-container" style="background: yellow">
  <figure><img src="https://placehold.it/100"></figure>
  <figure><img src="https://placehold.it/100"></figure>
  <figure><img src="https://placehold.it/100"></figure>
  <figure><img src="https://placehold.it/100"></figure>
  <figure><img src="https://placehold.it/100"></figure>
</div>
```

Стоит учесть, что пробелы между элементами такого контейнера имеют существенное значение для распределения объектов по горизонтали. Чтобы они не влияли на минимальное расстояние между фигурами, обнуляется размер шрифта в контейнере.

Из недостатков следует упомянуть необходимость возвращения этих свойств в своё первоначальное значение и невозможность прозрачно наследовать размер текста от родительских тегов.

Кроме того, нужно учесть, что последняя строка таки съезжает, ломая средние колонки.

[image: пример кривого расположения элементов]

Для выравнивания по вертикали надо использовать полузабытое свойство **vertical-align**.

Answer (score 2):

Иной подход заключается в использовании ещё нестандизированного свойства **columns** с указанием желаемой ширины колонки. В этом же и есть основной минус данного подхода — нужно знать размеры вложенных элементов. Кроме того, объекты следуют в вертикальном порядке, как при задании `flex-direction: column`.

```css
.product-container {
  columns: 150px;
}
.product-container > * {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-container" style="background: yellow">
  <figure><img src="https://placehold.it/100"></figure>
  <figure><img src="https://placehold.it/100"></figure>
  <figure><img src="https://placehold.it/100"></figure>
  <figure><img src="https://placehold.it/100"></figure>
  <figure><img src="https://placehold.it/100"></figure>
</div>
```